# Update output inserted #temp query hangs on prod

Tags: sql-server, performance

Below query is inside Stored procedure. It runs smoothly on sofar. Today suddenly it hung on prod. When I do a select removing UPDATE it returns ZERO records.

```
UPDATE STG SET STATUS = 'D' 
                    OUTPUT INSERTED.TRACKING_ID INTO #TEMP (TID)
                    FROM STAGE_TABLE STG(NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN STAGE_PRE_ACC  PRE(NOLOCK)
                    ON PRE.ID=STG.ID AND 
PRE.CID=STG.CID 
                    WHERE PRE.STATUS = 'D'
                    AND STG.ETLNBR < PRE.ETLNBR
```

Answer (score 0):

The data might have changed so as making an original plan inefficient. Try clearing it from the plan cache:

```
SELECT qtext.text,qstats.plan_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qstats
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qstats.plan_handle) as qtext
where text like 'UPDATE STG SET STATUS = ''D''%';
```

Get the correct plan handle and flush it:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (<put plan handle here>)
```

Comment: My DBA is not recommending for clearance of execution plan. Could you please suggest if we can do it for one specific query? or it will flush complete DB execution plan?

Comment: @YounusMohammed The script above will just clear the one plan. The correct plan handle is found in the first query; place that handle into the parameter brackets on the second statement.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing in plan. It has returned nothing. Will you be able to help in rewriting this query?

Comment: @YounusMohammed If you change the last line to: WHERE TEXT LIKE '%UPDATE STG%' - then maybe you will see it